# GWT_HOME on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, gwt

I installed GWT through the Zip provided in their website for Eclipse Indigo.

However when I try to run a project (not a new WebApplication, that works) it says BUILD FAILED ....../${env.GWT_HOME} does not exist.

How do I set GWT_HOME on Eclipse and how do I know the location of GWT_HOME if it was all installed by Eclipse automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

**Option 1** - For easy maintenance

1) Download the GWT directly from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list)
2) In eclipse goto `Windows -> Preference -> Google -> Web Toolkit -> Add` ( Configure GWT version, location and name in popup)

3) You can set up multiple GWT versions and set one of them as default.

[image]

**Option 2**

1) grep/search for gwt-user*.jar in your eclipe folder ( dropins,plugins,features,p2 !!!! )

2) Configure classpath variable GWT_HOME. Goto **"Windows -> Preference -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variable -> New"**

[image]