# GWT_HOME does not exist (mac 10.8.3)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, gwt

I'm running Eclipse Juno on a mac os 10.8.3.
I installed GWT (2.5.2) plugin with eclipse, but when I try to run my project, there's always this error:

```
BUILD FAILED 
/../../${env.GWT_HOME} does not exist.
```

Also on my build file, in the following line:

```
<taskdef resource="dml-ant.xml" classpathref="project.classpath"/>
```

It shows an error with the same thing.

Now I've seen both [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031079/gwt-home-on-mac) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540620/the-project-xxx-does-not-have-any-gwt-sdks-on-its-build-path?rq=1) threads but none of the solutions worked.

Outside of eclipse I've GWT_HOME defined in the .profile file, as this:

```
export GWT_HOME=/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.5.1
```

Inside Eclipse, I have this configurations:

```
- Preferences->Google->Web Toolkit-> GWT::2.5.1::[Location of the gwt-2.5.1 folder in plugins]
- Preferences->Java->Build Path->Classpath Variables-> GWT_HOME [defined to the same place]
```

In my project:

```
- Properties->Google->Web Toolkit (only one selected)-> Use default SDK (GWT - 2.5.1)
- Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export->GWT SDK [GWT - 2.5.1] almost on top (above maven libraries, at least)
```

I've tried some stuff like changing the gwt-2.5.1 folder (and the GWT_HOME path with it), reinstalled several times and with older versions, several restarts both to eclipse and the computer, etc.
I may be missing something obvious here, it's the first I'm working with GWT (and one of the firsts with Eclipse).

Thanks in advance for all your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is setup with ant, isn't it?, If so:

It seems your ant file build.xml does not have the line:

```
 <property environment=”env”/>
```

It would be happenning as well that when running eclipse it does not pick up the environment variables you set in your .profile, maybe you have to launch eclipse from the command-line.

Eventually, as a quick fix edit your ant.xml file and replace all occurrences of ${env.GWT_HOME} by /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.5.1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, my project is ant build and I have that line in build.xml. Running from the command-line works :) I've reinstalled eclipse and the plugins, and it still only works with the command-line. Does this mean eclipse doesn't have privileges to access the variables?

Comment: No, that means that the desktop session does not read your `.profile` but the `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` file. In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion) thread you can know how to set variables for X applications.